# Get number of concurrent tests running in AVA

Tags: javascript, typescript, ava

I have test cases that are failing due timestamp differences as a result of a lot of tests running at once.  I want to adjust the difference depending on the number of test cases running at point in time.

Is there a way to get the number of test cases that AVA is currently running?  It doesn't appear that a search has a lot of information on this issue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add a brief description, code, errors of your search/research efforts as is suggested.

Comment: @PrathameshMore I added a description.  Anything more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No AVA does not provide this.

Why do you encounter timestamp differences? Might your tests be too brittle?

Perhaps it'll help if you use `test.serial()`?

Comment: Is it possible to request for this feature then?  Running tests on a local machine is fine.  Once I run them on an CI environment, then these issues show up

Comment: No. Your tests shouldn't be failing on CI for timestamp reasons. You need to consider if you're testing the right thing.